# R using gsub to escape parentheses in a string leads to double backslashes

Tags: r

I ran into this problem while generating filenames from a vector of variable names. I have a string variable that contains "(" and ")", and I want to properly escape these characters to use as a filename argument for a writer function (specifically ggsave in this case). I've been trying to use gsub, which gets me so close.

```
problem_string = "Weird_(filename).txt"

gsub("([\\(\\)])", "\\\\\\1", problem_string)
# [1] "Weird_\\(filename\\).txt"
gsub("([\\(\\)])", "\\\\\1", problem_string)
# [1] "Weird_\\\001filename\\\001.txt"
```

I can only seem to get double backslashes. At first I thought this was some interaction with the look-behind operator, but it persists if I try to replace just one parenthesis.

```
gsub("\\(", "\\\\\\(", problem_string)
# [1] "Weird_\\(filename).txt"
gsub("\\(", "\\\\(", problem_string)
# [1] "Weird_\\(filename).txt"
gsub("\\(", "\\(", problem_string)
# [1] "Weird_(filename).txt"
```

Basically, there doesn't appear to be a way to get a single backslash. It's two or none. This seems like a strange behavior.

**UPDATE(01/29/2018)**:

First off, after taking suggestions from the comments I found out that my original problem was actually with including a "%" in the filename argument with the ggsave function, specifically. I incorrectly identified parentheses in the filename as the culprits, and dropped the "%" from my simplified example in this post. However, I did find some interesting behavior with the use of backslashes and special characters in strings used as filename arguments in R, so I've included the additional explorations below.

So R treats the escaped backslash as a single character under the hood:

```
strsplit(gsub("([\\(\\)])", "\\\\\\1", problem_string), "")
# [[1]]
#  [1] "M"  "e"  "a"  "n"  "_"  "H"  "R"  "_"  "\\" "("  "b"  "e"  "a"  "t"  "s"  "-"  "m"  "i"  "n"  "\\" ")"  "."  "."  "."  "T"  "i"  "m"  "e"  "_"  "D" 
# [31] "o"  "m"  "a"  "i"  "n"  "_"  "R"  "e"  "s"  "u"  "l"  "t"  "s"  "."  "."  "."  "S"  "t"  "a"  "t"  "i"  "s"  "t"  "i"  "c"  "a"  "l"  "_"  "p"  "a" 
# [61] "r"  "a"  "m"  "e"  "t"  "e"  "r"  "s"
```

And when I use cat, the double backslash gets evaluated as a single backslash:

```
cat(gsub("([\\(\\)])", "\\\\\\1", problem_string))
# Weird_\(filename\).txt
```

However, no such evaluation occurs when I'm using the string output of gsub as the filename argument in a file write command:

```
write.table(c("test"), gsub("([\\(\\)])", "\\\\\\1", problem_string))

list.files(pattern = "Weird")
# [1] "Weird_\\(filename\\).txt"
```

When I go to a terminal and run an "ls" on the directory where this file is saved I can confirm that the filename includes the backslashes: it is saved as *Weird_\(filename\).txt*. As it turns out, to save a filename with parentheses I didn't need to mess around with escape characters.

```
write.table(c("test"), "Weird_(filename).txt")

list.files(pattern = "Weird")
# [1] "Weird_(filename).txt"     "Weird_\\(filename\\).txt"
```

So R's write functions are smart enough to handle these special characters in the filename arguments, without requiring the user to explicitly escape them. When I did try to escape the parentheses with the backslashes, R included those in the filename as well.

Comment: what is your expected results ?

Comment: The first `gsub` already provides one backslash before each (.  The only reason you see two is that R doubles it within double quotes but the extra backslash is not part of the string.  Try `cat(gsub(....))` to see what is really in the output string.  Also try `strsplit(gsub(...), "")` to confirm the individual characters in the output string.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for pointing out my error. I've updated the post based on your comments and found out I didn't even have a problem with parentheses to begin with. I want to give you credit for the solve, so I'll leave the question open for a few days to give you a chance to post an answer. Thanks again!